# Can I git clone into a directory without cloning the project name as a directory (using bitbucket)?

Tags: linux, centos, git

I'm a small business and for the most part only use git locally to track history then SFTP the files to the remote server.

I now have a much larger more complicated build that to be set up properly requires a production, a staging, and a development server.

I'm trying to set up git so I can merge changes from development and push/pull to the staging environment for deployment testing, then again to production.

So far, I've installed git on production and development. I've also created a Repo via Bitbucket and commit/pushed the contents of my httpdocs folder to master. I thought this would mean I can simply clone then branch directly into my httpdocs folder on development.

However, when I tried to pull these files into the development environement to make the development branch it included a folder with my project name(I never created this folder). I ended up with httpdocs/MyProjectName/Files

My questions are:

1. Did I do something wrong in setup?
2. Is there a way to configure git so it knows I want the files not the containing directory?
3. Can I clone in a way that only pulls the contents of MyProjectName but not the directory?

I don't want my workflow to include pull then copy to httpdocs.

Comment: are there files in httpdocs that aren't in your repo?

Comment: I initially thought the OP misspelled "gitbucket" - turns out there's an [actual project](https://github.com/takezoe/gitbucket) behind it.

Comment: @skarface no there aren't

Comment: @Isxek I did make a typo. I'm referring to http://bitbucket.org/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
git clone [repository] [local path]
```

If your working directory is your desired destination, simply put a `.`

```
$ git clone git@repo-site.com .
```

Comment: Note: the directory you want to clone into, here called `[local_path]`, must be empty

Comment: This works for one project level, how about if I have two folders I want to skip?

Comment: @Bionix1441 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326365/git-clone-ignoring-a-directory

Comment: Thank you, the sparsecheckout would not work for me, since I am using maven plugin for Jenkins, and I only specify the URL of the repository to clone. May be the easiest solution is to remove the second wrapping folder.